# jquery validation of multiselect on form submission

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, multi-select

this is my cshtml code for multiselect   [the cshtml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWmH7.png)

```
<select class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="Staff ID/ Student name" asp-for="User Ids"        asp-items="@(new Select List (Model .Users, "Id", "Name"))" required>
 <option></option>>
 </select>
  <label>Staff ID/ Student name<i>&#42;</i></label>
 </div>'
```

and this is my jquery

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
            errorLabelContainer: $("#disciplinaryTicketCreate input.error"),

        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#disciplinaryTicketCreate").validate({
                rules: {
                    description: {
                        maxlength: 256,
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    description: {
                        maxlength: "must be below 256 characters"
                    }
                },
                errorElement: "span",
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parent("div").find(".errors"));
                },
            });
        });
```

what should I do make the user select at least one of the multiselect ??

form id="disciplinaryTicketCreate"

Comment: *"what should I do make the user select at least one of the multiselect?"*  The `required` rule will force the user to select at least one option.  Since you have the `required` rule applied via the `required` inline attribute, this should already be working as described.

Comment: @Sparky but it doesn't work !!

Comment: And your question is lacking the details that shows us why.